# Google Maps API Javascript: DirectionsService.route is not an Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm trying to create my first script using Google Maps.
I've to create a route between point A and B, with certain waypoints in the middle (A and B will be the first and last objects of the json with addresses).
This is my code:

```
<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
    var map = null;
    var positions = [];
    var geocoder = null;
    var directionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = null;
    var json =
        [{ "id": "511", "nome": "PERSONA_511", "indirizzo": "VIA DEI COLLI", "civico": "17", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:42:00" }, { "id": "562", "nome": "PERSONA_562", "indirizzo": "VIA DEI COLOMBI", "civico": "45", "comune": "terni", "orario": "07:57:00" }, { "id": "584", "nome": "PERSONA_584", "indirizzo": "VIA MACINAROTTA", "civico": "22", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:47:00" }, { "id": "621", "nome": "PERSONA_621", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "94", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:55:00" }, { "id": "622", "nome": "PERSONA_622", "indirizzo": "VIA CASELLA ALFREDO", "civico": "33", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:35:00" }, { "id": "626", "nome": "PERSONA_626", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL CAPRIOLO", "civico": "12\/B", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "08:30:00" }, { "id": "643", "nome": "PERSONA_643", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL FALCO", "civico": "59", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "08:35:00" }, { "id": "702", "nome": "PERSONA_702", "indirizzo": "VIA PIZZETTI ILDEBRANDO", "civico": "7", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:36:00" }, { "id": "753", "nome": "PERSONA_753", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL POZZO SARACENO", "civico": "13", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:50:00" }, { "id": "780", "nome": "PERSONA_780", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLE CINQUE STRADE", "civico": "41", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:37:00" }, { "id": "781", "nome": "PERSONA_781", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLE CINQUE STRADE", "civico": "41", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:37:00" }, { "id": "786", "nome": "PERSONA_786", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI SANTA MARIA LA ROCCA", "civico": "13", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:41:00" }, { "id": "803", "nome": "PERSONA_803", "indirizzo": "VIA MACINAROTTA", "civico": "60", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:49:00" }, { "id": "805", "nome": "PERSONA_805", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "26", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:33:00" }, { "id": "1199", "nome": "PERSONA_1199", "indirizzo": "VIA CASELLA ALFREDO", "civico": "23", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:38:00" }, { "id": "1200", "nome": "PERSONA_1200", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "100", "comune": "TERNI", "orario": "07:58:00" }, { "id": "1322", "nome": "PERSONA_1322", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI PIEDIMONTE", "civico": "33", "comune": "terni", "orario": "08:22:00" }, { "id": "1423", "nome": "PERSONA_1420", "indirizzo": "VIA SCARLATTI DOMENICO", "civico": "12", "comune": "", "orario": "07:55:00" }, { "id": "1954", "nome": "PERSONA_511", "indirizzo": "VIA DEI COLLI", "civico": "17", "comune": "", "orario": "07:48:00" }, { "id": "2004", "nome": "PERSONA_562", "indirizzo": "VIA DEI COLOMBI", "civico": "45", "comune": "", "orario": "08:02:00" }, { "id": "2026", "nome": "PERSONA_584", "indirizzo": "VIA MACINAROTTA", "civico": "22", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "2061", "nome": "PERSONA_621", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "94", "comune": "", "orario": "07:58:00" }, { "id": "2062", "nome": "PERSONA_622", "indirizzo": "VIA CASELLA ALFREDO", "civico": "33", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "2065", "nome": "PERSONA_626", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL CAPRIOLO", "civico": "12\/B", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "2082", "nome": "PERSONA_643", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL FALCO", "civico": "59", "comune": "", "orario": "08:32:00" }, { "id": "2138", "nome": "PERSONA_702", "indirizzo": "VIA PIZZETTI ILDEBRANDO", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "07:40:00" }, { "id": "2185", "nome": "PERSONA_753", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL POZZO SARACENO", "civico": "13", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "2211", "nome": "PERSONA_780", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLE CINQUE STRADE", "civico": "41", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "2212", "nome": "PERSONA_781", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLE CINQUE STRADE", "civico": "41", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "2217", "nome": "PERSONA_786", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI SANTA MARIA LA ROCCA", "civico": "13", "comune": "", "orario": "07:45:00" }, { "id": "2234", "nome": "PERSONA_803", "indirizzo": "VIA MACINAROTTA", "civico": "60", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "2236", "nome": "PERSONA_805", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "26", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "2935", "nome": "PERSONA_1540", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "26", "comune": "", "orario": "07:33:00" }, { "id": "3106", "nome": "PERSONA_1711", "indirizzo": "VIA PONTE LE CAVE", "civico": "14\/F", "comune": "", "orario": "08:45:00" }, { "id": "3185", "nome": "PERSONA_1790", "indirizzo": "VIA TOSCANINI ARTURO", "civico": "18", "comune": "", "orario": "07:42:00" }, { "id": "3257", "nome": "PERSONA_1862", "indirizzo": "VIA COLLE DELL'ORO", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "08:47:00" }, {
            "id": "3258", "nome": "PERSONA_1863",
            "indirizzo": "VIA MONTE TOTAGNA", "civico": "87", "comune": "", "orario": "08:50:00"
        }, { "id": "3410", "nome": "PERSONA_1199", "indirizzo": "VIA CASELLA ALFREDO", "civico": "23", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3411", "nome": "PERSONA_1200", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "100", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3835", "nome": "PERSONA_562", "indirizzo": "VIA DEI COLOMBI", "civico": "45", "comune": "", "orario": "08:03:00" }, { "id": "3853", "nome": "PERSONA_584", "indirizzo": "VIA MACINAROTTA", "civico": "22", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3879", "nome": "PERSONA_621", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "94", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3880", "nome": "PERSONA_622", "indirizzo": "VIA CASELLA ALFREDO", "civico": "33", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3882", "nome": "PERSONA_626", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL CAPRIOLO", "civico": "12\/B", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3892", "nome": "PERSONA_643", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL FALCO", "civico": "59", "comune": "", "orario": "08:30:00" }, { "id": "3935", "nome": "PERSONA_702", "indirizzo": "VIA PIZZETTI ILDEBRANDO", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "07:40:00" }, { "id": "3963", "nome": "PERSONA_753", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL POZZO SARACENO", "civico": "13", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3987", "nome": "PERSONA_779", "indirizzo": "VIA TOSCANINI ARTURO", "civico": "21", "comune": "", "orario": "07:41:00" }, { "id": "3988", "nome": "PERSONA_780", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLE CINQUE STRADE", "civico": "41", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3989", "nome": "PERSONA_781", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLE CINQUE STRADE", "civico": "41", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "3993", "nome": "PERSONA_786", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI SANTA MARIA LA ROCCA", "civico": "13", "comune": "", "orario": "07:45:00" }, { "id": "4005", "nome": "PERSONA_803", "indirizzo": "VIA MACINAROTTA", "civico": "60", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "4006", "nome": "PERSONA_805", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "26", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "4366", "nome": "PERSONA_1327", "indirizzo": "VIA CARNANO", "civico": "26", "comune": "", "orario": "08:57:00" }, { "id": "4508", "nome": "PERSONA_1540", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "26", "comune": "", "orario": "07:38:00" }, { "id": "4758", "nome": "PERSONA_1863", "indirizzo": "VIA MONTE TOTAGNA", "civico": "87", "comune": "", "orario": "08:55:00" }, { "id": "4865", "nome": "PERSONA_2012", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL TORDO", "civico": "63", "comune": "", "orario": "07:37:00" }, { "id": "4866", "nome": "PERSONA_2013", "indirizzo": "VIALE BATTISTI CESARE", "civico": "167", "comune": "", "orario": "07:30:00" }, { "id": "5042", "nome": "PERSONA_2189", "indirizzo": "VIA TOSCANINI ARTURO", "civico": "21", "comune": "", "orario": "07:41:00" }, { "id": "5145", "nome": "PERSONA_2292", "indirizzo": "VIA MASCAGNI PIETRO", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "5155", "nome": "PERSONA_2302", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL FAGGIO", "civico": "33", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "5271", "nome": "PERSONA_1322", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI PIEDIMONTE", "civico": "33", "comune": "", "orario": "07:38:00" }, { "id": "5275", "nome": "PERSONA_1420", "indirizzo": "VIA SCARLATTI DOMENICO", "civico": "12", "comune": "", "orario": "07:57:00" }, { "id": "5338", "nome": "PERSONA_511", "indirizzo": "VIA DEI COLLI", "civico": "17", "comune": "", "orario": "07:52:00" }, { "id": "5353", "nome": "PERSONA_643", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL FALCO", "civico": "59", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "5483", "nome": "PERSONA_1597", "indirizzo": "VIA GIOVANNINI GIUSEPPE", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "07:15:00" }, { "id": "5484", "nome": "PERSONA_1598", "indirizzo": "VIA GIOVANNINI GIUSEPPE", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "07:15:00" }, { "id": "5507", "nome": "PERSONA_1711", "indirizzo": "VIA PONTE LE CAVE", "civico": "14\/F", "comune": "", "orario": "08:28:00" }, { "id": "5519", "nome": "PERSONA_1790", "indirizzo": "VIA TOSCANINI ARTURO", "civico": "18", "comune": "", "orario": "07:32:00" }, { "id": "5527", "nome": "PERSONA_803", "indirizzo": "VIA MACINAROTTA", "civico": "60", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "5634", "nome": "PERSONA_1199", "indirizzo": "VIA CASELLA ALFREDO", "civico": "23", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "5635", "nome": "PERSONA_1200", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "100", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "6035", "nome": "PERSONA_584", "indirizzo": "VIA MACINAROTTA", "civico": "22", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "6057", "nome": "PERSONA_621", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "94", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "6058", "nome": "PERSONA_622", "indirizzo": "VIA CASELLA ALFREDO", "civico": "33", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "6060", "nome": "PERSONA_626", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL CAPRIOLO", "civico": "12\/B", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "6105", "nome": "PERSONA_702", "indirizzo": "VIA PIZZETTI ILDEBRANDO", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "07:30:00" }, { "id": "6151", "nome": "PERSONA_780", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLE CINQUE STRADE", "civico": "41", "comune": "", "orario": "07:43:00" }, { "id": "6152", "nome": "PERSONA_781", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLE CINQUE STRADE", "civico": "41", "comune": "", "orario": "07:43:00" }, { "id": "6155", "nome": "PERSONA_786", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI SANTA MARIA LA ROCCA", "civico": "13", "comune": "", "orario": "07:50:00" }, { "id": "6167", "nome": "PERSONA_805", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "26", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "6594", "nome": "PERSONA_1540", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL RIVO", "civico": "26", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }, { "id": "6811", "nome": "PERSONA_1862", "indirizzo": "VIA COLLE DELL'ORO", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "09:00:00" }, { "id": "6812", "nome": "PERSONA_1863", "indirizzo": "VIA MONTE TOTAGNA", "civico": "87", "comune": "", "orario": "08:55:00" }, { "id": "6818", "nome": "PERSONA_1884", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI PALMETTA", "civico": "32", "comune": "", "orario": "07:47:00" }, { "id": "6907", "nome": "PERSONA_2012", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL TORDO", "civico": "63", "comune": "", "orario": "07:27:00" }, { "id": "6908", "nome": "PERSONA_2013", "indirizzo": "VIALE BATTISTI CESARE", "civico": "167", "comune": "", "orario": "07:20:00" }, { "id": "6950", "nome": "PERSONA_2059", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL GERMANO", "civico": "1", "comune": "", "orario": "07:31:00" }, { "id": "7114", "nome": "PERSONA_2231", "indirizzo": "VIA TOSCANINI ARTURO", "civico": "18", "comune": "", "orario": "07:32:00" }, { "id": "7147", "nome": "PERSONA_2265", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI SAN FORTUNATO", "civico": "31", "comune": "", "orario": "08:36:00" }, { "id": "7171", "nome": "PERSONA_2290", "indirizzo": "VIA PIEMONTE", "civico": "2", "comune": "", "orario": "08:45:00" }, { "id": "7214", "nome": "PERSONA_2337", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI SAN FORTUNATO", "civico": "31", "comune": "", "orario": "08:36:00" }, { "id": "7235", "nome": "PERSONA_2358", "indirizzo": "VIA SCARLATTI DOMENICO", "civico": "12", "comune": "", "orario": "07:57:00" }, { "id": "7238", "nome": "PERSONA_2361", "indirizzo": "VIA COLLE DELL'ORO", "civico": "7", "comune": "", "orario": "09:00:00" }, { "id": "7290", "nome": "PERSONA_2413", "indirizzo": "VIA DELLA CASTELLINA", "civico": "15", "comune": "", "orario": "07:24:00" }, { "id": "7360", "nome": "PERSONA_2483", "indirizzo": "VIA PONTE LE CAVE", "civico": "13\/B", "comune": "", "orario": "08:32:00" }, { "id": "7369", "nome": "PERSONA_2492", "indirizzo": "VIA TOSCANINI ARTURO", "civico": "55", "comune": "", "orario": "07:48:00" }, { "id": "7380", "nome": "PERSONA_2503", "indirizzo": "VIA MONTE TOTAGNA", "civico": "87", "comune": "", "orario": "08:55:00" }, { "id": "7384", "nome": "PERSONA_2507", "indirizzo": "VIA TOSCANINI ARTURO", "civico": "55b", "comune": "", "orario": "07:55:00" }, { "id": "7456", "nome": "PERSONA_2579", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL GERMANO", "civico": "37", "comune": "", "orario": "07:50:00" }, { "id": "7485", "nome": "PERSONA_2608", "indirizzo": "VIA DONIZETTI GAETANO", "civico": "67", "comune": "", "orario": "08:19:00" }, { "id": "7486", "nome": "PERSONA_2609", "indirizzo": "STRADA DI PIEDIMONTE", "civico": "111", "comune": "", "orario": "08:25:00" }, { "id": "7557", "nome": "PERSONA_2680", "indirizzo": "VIALE BATTISTI CESARE", "civico": "167", "comune": "", "orario": "07:20:00" }, { "id": "7562", "nome": "PERSONA_2685", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL POZZO SARACENO", "civico": "45", "comune": "", "orario": "08:20:00" }, { "id": "7582", "nome": "PERSONA_2705", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL CAPRIOLO", "civico": "1", "comune": "", "orario": "08:25:00" }, { "id": "7612", "nome": "PERSONA_2735", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL TORDO", "civico": "63", "comune": "", "orario": "07:27:00" }, { "id": "7613", "nome": "PERSONA_2736", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL TORDO", "civico": "63", "comune": "", "orario": "07:27:00" }, { "id": "7752", "nome": "PERSONA_2875", "indirizzo": "VIA DEL TORDO", "civico": "77", "comune": "", "orario": "00:00:00" }];

    function myMap() {
        // Instantiate a directions service.
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 5,
            apTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        console.log(directionsService);

        // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ map: map });
        console.log(directionsDisplay);

        // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
        var stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        cicloIndirizzi();
    }

    function cicloIndirizzi() {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var obj = json[i];
            (function (i, obj) {
                setTimeout(function (i) {
                    codeAddress(geocoder, map, obj)
                }, i * 1000);
            })(i, obj);
        }
    }

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute() {
        // Retrieve the start and end locations and create a DirectionsRequest using
        // WALKING directions.
        console.log("ORIGIN: "+ positions[0]);
        console.log("DESTINATION: "+ positions[positions.length - 1]);
        var request = {
            origin: positions[0],
            destination: positions[positions.length - 1],
            travelMode: 'WALKING'
        }
        //waypoints: positions,
        //optimizeWaypoints: true,
        directionsService.route(function (response, status) {
            // Route the directions and pass the response to a function to create
            // markers for each step.
            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }

    function codeAddress(geocoder, map, obj) {
        var stringaIndirizzo = obj["indirizzo"];
        if (obj["civico"] != "") {
            stringaIndirizzo = stringaIndirizzo + ", " + obj["civico"];
        }
        if (obj["comune"] != "") {
            stringaIndirizzo = stringaIndirizzo + ", " + obj["comune"];
        }
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': stringaIndirizzo, 'region': 'IT' }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: obj["nome"]
                });
                //marker.metadata = { type: "point", id: 1 };
                marker.addListener('click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                positions.push(marker.position);
                console.log(directionsService);

                calculateAndDisplayRoute();

                console.log("RICERCA...")
            } else {
                console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAzmz6WLUQToLaAgy8zu_pud0I59wHTB2M&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Problem is when I try to call **directionsService.route()** I get an error:

> InvalidValueError: not an Object

I can't understand why I can't use the route function of directionsService and I'm stuck. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You need to invoke the constructor, even if you aren't passing it any arguments. Compare what you do with `Map`, `Geocoder`, and `DirectionsRenderer` with what you do with `DirectionsService` and `InfoWindow`

Comment: You have a typo in the call to `directionsService.route`.  The first argument should be `request` (so it should be: `directionsService.route(request,function(response, status) {`, not `directionsService.route(function (response, status) {`) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d5wm0qx7/2/))

Comment: The constructor for the DirectionsService is OK.